# BLOCKCHAIN BASED ADMISSION SYSTEM

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, blockchain

I am totaly new to `solidity`, but I am trying to create admin account with '**owner permission**' in the `smart contract` to deduct gas fees from owner's account (university account for example).

- If owner decline the transaction admin would not be able to create account.
- Then, I want register student with '**admin permission**' and deduct `gas fees` from owner's account (university account), and if admin decline the transaction, student would not be able to create account.

Is that possible? How could I do that.

Comment: Let me know if the answer was helpful or to delete it! @Saira Rao

Answer (score 0):

This can help you about Smart contract '**permissions**' ;)

> Basic permission checks in Smart Contracts verify that the calling user is the owner of the contract. For this approach, the contract inherits from a contract like the owned in Core.sol:

```
contract Owned {
    address public owner;

    function Owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) only_owner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }

    // This only allows the owner to perform function
    modifier only_owner {
      assert(msg.sender == owner);
      _;
    }
}
```

Contract transactions that should only be used by the contract owner use the only_owner modifier, can have its storage only be set by the owner.

```
contract OwnedStorage is Owned {
    string public data;

    function setData(string newData) public only_owner {
        data = newData;
    }
}
```

The **Owned contract** provides sufficient permissions for easy contracts or contracts with only one contributor and many consumers, but fails to support different contract structures with different `roles`.

If a contract has a function that only a specific scope of users are allowed to use, the contract has to inherit from `DSAuth`. This adds the authority property to the contract and allows to use the auth modifier. An authority is a contract that inherits from `DSAuth`. To use roles for contract permissions, the authority can be an instance of `DSRoles`. Using this in the previous example, the contract looks like this:

```
contract OwnedStorage is DSAuth {
    string public data;

    function setData(string newData) public auth {
        data = newData;
    }
```

You can find the entire explanation in this post [SmartContracts Permissioning](https://evannetwork.github.io/docs/developers/concepts/smart-contract-permissioning.html).